# Interpreting parameters on Matlab from Patons code on time varying copulas

Tags: programming, copula, dynamic, markov-switching, normal

I ran Andrew pattons code(2006) for Markov switching time varying copulas with an example code given in the Matlab tool box. This is the equation for Markov switching time varying normal copulas

[image]

I dont understand how to read the parameters, as shown below which I am getting after running the Matlab code. What am I missing.

[image]

The link to the original paper and the upgraded matlab is below

https://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/1794/1/WRAP_Patton_fwp04-04.pdf
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46597-markov_copula_code-zip

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In order to get any help, you need to provide a link for the Matlab code and the paper in question.

Comment: The initial parameters from the vector $\kappa_0$ in the ```main_example.m``` Matlab code refers to the parameters, $\kappa_0=\{\omega_0, \omega_1, \alpha, \beta, p, q\}$. The $\omega_i$ are the constants for state $i=0,1$, $\beta$ is the autoregressive parameter and $\alpha$ is the same as $\gamma$ in your equation.  The constants $p$ and $q$ are transformed to probabilities within the ```markovnormal.m``` function. The optimized parameters probably follows from the vector ```param21``` (I don't have the tools to run the code). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you soooo much @Pleb. Yes this was exactly my main concern. I did not think of looking inside markovnormal.m function. I was just looking inside the bivariate normal tvp. Also what was confusing me was, if last two values are probabilities, why am I getting them as 4.416 and 5.1514....And the initial values of κ0={1,5,0,0,4,5} also still dont make sense. Can you give your input about these two issues.

Comment: The last two values are not probabilities but just constants that are transformed to probabilities within the ```markovnormal.m``` file, using the [logistic sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). To get the probabilities, you need to respectively insert 4.416 and 5.1514 into the logistic sigmoid function, $\sigma(x) = \frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$, which evidently transforms them into a number between $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Pleb. Thanks a ton. Thank you very very much.